# highlight a part of the cell when selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to add a non-standard color to the cell when its highlighted. FOr this i create a view with the background color that i want and set it as the `selectedBackgroundView` for the cell.

All is fine.

> ```
> UIView *selectionView = [[UIView alloc] init];
> [selectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(121/255.0) green:(201/255.0) blue:(209/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
> [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectionView];
> ```

My question, can i change the frame of the `selectedBackgroundView` so that it highlights only a part of the cell (to be precise, i want the selectionBackroundView to have an X-offset of 20 pixels).

is there any easy way of doing this ?

Updated code :

> ```
> UIView *selectionView = [[UIView alloc] init];
> [selectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
> ```

```
UIView *selectionSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(20.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 72.0f))];
[selectionSubView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(121/255.0) green:(201/255.0) blue:(209/255.0) alpha:1.0]];

UIView *clearView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 72.0f))];
[clearView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

[selectionView addSubview: selectionSubView];
[selectionView addSubview: clearView];

[cell setSelectedBackgroundView: selectionView];
```

THis doesn seem to work either. I have added this code in the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'

Thanks in advance

Comment: bit in an hurry, can't compile it now, but have you tryed setting the selectionView frame explicitly? 'cause if it don't have a specific frame when you add the subviews the result can be uncorrect (subviews coordinates are relative to parent, but if parent haven't...).

Answer (score 1):

You could put a smaller UIView as subview of your selectionView and change tha background color of that view.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

You create the separate file for UIView as below.

TestView.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

/* Draw a circle */
// Get the contextRef
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Set the border width
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 1.0);

// Set the circle fill color to GREEN
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 100.0, 255.0, 0.0, 1.0);

// Set the cicle border color to BLUE
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 1.0);

// Fill the circle with the fill color
CGContextFillRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(20, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));

// Draw the circle border
//CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(contextRef, rect, 10);//(contextRef, rect);
}
```

And this Custom View you can use as a background View for cell selection like this.

```
    TestView *bgView = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame]; // Creating a view for the background...this seems to be required.
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
```

May be this help you.

Thanks,

Minesh Purohit.

Answer (score 0):

Does the cell have fixed size and highlight area ?

If yes, create an image and use image view as the selectedBackgroundView

Answer (score -1):

Try to set frame size for selectionView where x = 20. I am not sure about this but I guess it should work for your given scenario.